# Combining Form fields in $header CC:

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me on how to combine multiple form fields (which contain email addresses) and incorporate them into a $header CC: ?

I currently have this:

```
$headers .= 'CC: <'.$_POST['submitted_by'] ."> \r\nReply-To:<".$_POST['submitted_by'].">";
```

which works fine but I now need to add another field "sales" to the Cc: and everything I try does not work.

Comment: Please read this article about mail header injection.  Using `$_POST` values unmodified in mail headers is a surefire way for your webform to become a spam source. http://www.phpsecure.info/v2/article/MailHeadersInject.en.php

Comment: really I've been taking shots in the dark as I have barely any php experience and am working off an older template. As for the spam, that's not a concern as it's only an internal form within a company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to make it more "readable".

Try something like this:

```
$headers .="CC:<{$_POST['submitted_by']}>";
$headers .="\r\n";
$headers .="Reply-To:<{$_POST['submitted_by']}>";
```

Now, can't you just put it in the next line of the CC? I don't see where the problem is.

```
$headers .="CC:<{$_POST['submitted_by']}>";
$headers .=",<{$_POST['sales']}>";
$headers .="\r\n";
$headers .="Reply-To:<{$_POST['submitted_by']}>";
```

Last but not least. Remember to filter the fields! To prevent header injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Verify submitted_by is a valid email address first and contains no line breaks
// Look elsewhere for how to do this.

// Additional addresses are comma-separated.
$headers .= "CC: $validated_submitted_by, $sales_addr\r\n";
$headers .= //other headers.
```